# STREAMLIT: How to print the output of a function

Tags: function, data-science, streamlit

I have this function:

```
def hello (name):
    return ('Hello ', name)

first_variable = hello('Maya')
st.text(first_variable)
```

I want to see ‘Hello Maya’ in my web app, but I get: ‘None’

What should I do?

Comment: You're passing a tuple into `st.text`; perhaps you mean to pass a string?

Answer (score 2):

As well said by Jared, you're returning a tuple ans his answer is perfect.

In addition to his answer, I'd like to update some `streamlit` command.

```
def hello(name):
    return "Hello " + name

first_variable = st.text_input("What's your name?")
if first_variable:
    st.write(hello(first_variable))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a Tuple with `'Hello'` at the first index and the value of `name` in the second. If you remove the parentheses (which in Python creates a Tuple type) at your return and replace it with a string concatenation, it should return `'Hello Maya'`

```
def hello(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name
```